# How to use Kafka Stream sliding window to dynamically include enough data points

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka and steaming. We have a situation in which I think Kafka Streams sliding window could help, but I cannot find any documentation or examples that show how.

What I want to do:

For each new message from a Kafka topic, I want all the related messages within the last hour to be aggregated, and if there is fewer than x messages within the last hour, I want to find related events occurred in earlier time window.

For example, a new message has value like {'id': 123, 'timestamp': '2019-06-13 20:00:00', other key: other value}. I want to find all the messages retained in kafka that have values {'id':123, 'timestamp': }.

Problems I have encountered.

If there is no messages or only a few messages sent within the last hour, I want to search messages in the earlier time window until I found x messages or until the earliest timestamp reaches a fixed date time.

In python, I could use some recurrion or searching to look back in the historical data set, but I don't know how to do that in Kafka streaming.

Could anyone give some hint? Thank you.

Comment: There is not out-of-the-box support for what you want. You could try to implement it manually with the Processor API: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html

Answer (score 0):

@Lena as suggested by @Matthias I would use the processor API to handle this logic. You should be able to build and manipulate your own state-store.